"Cannot destructure property" error while cloning repository in GitKraken using Linux
When I try and clone a repository from a managed GitLab instance, it fails with this error:


Cannot destructure property 'keyState' of '(intermediate value) [wt]' as it is undefined.

This happens in the Repository Management tab when I click Clone repository on any element in a a list of uncloned repositories. I'm on Linux Ubuntu, the problem does not happen on my Windows partition.
If I clone the repository with another Git tool, GitKraken can properly locate it in the filesystem and manage it.
GitKraken support was not helpful and gave a generic suggestion to reset everything, which I did to no avail.
